# How to proceed to add a package through Conda.jl[Conda.add ]from Julia

Tags: package, julia, conda, package-managers

How to proceed to add a package through Coda.add. I am receiving the following alert and I don’t know how to proceed

```
Julia> Conda.add("scipy.optimize")
[ Info: Running `conda install -y scipy.optimize` in root environment
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - scipy.optimize

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.


ERROR: failed process: Process(setenv(`'C:\Users\user\.julia\conda\3\Scripts\conda.exe' install -y scipy.optimize`,["PATH=C:\\Users\\user\\.julia\\conda\\3\\Library\\bin;C:\\Users\\user\\.julia\\conda\\3\\Library\\bin;C:\\Rtools\\bin;C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\bin;C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\GitHubDesktop\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Windows;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.2\\bin;C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin;C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.33.1\\resources\\app\\apm\\bin;C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Julia-1.0.3\\bin;;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA Corporation\\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NVIDIA Corporation\\PhysX\\Common;C:\\Program Files\\netCDF 4.7.4\\bin;C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\bin;C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\GitHubDesktop\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Windows;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.2\\bin;C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.33.1\\resources\\app\\apm\\bin;C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Julia-1.0.3\\bin;C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin;C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Julia 1.5.1\\bin;;%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps", "USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=GALILEO", "HOMEPATH=\\Users\\user", "PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC", "SESSIONNAME=Console", "SYSTEMROOT=C:\\WINDOWS", "APPDATA=C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming", "PSMODULEPATH=C:\\Program Files\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\Wired Networking\\", "COMMONPROGRAMW6432=C:\\Program Files\\Common Files", "PROGRAMDATA=C:\\ProgramData"  …  "PROGRAMFILES=C:\\Program Files", "CHOCOLATEYLASTPATHUPDATE=132430196948222515", "LOGONSERVER=\\\\GALILEO", "DRIVERDATA=C:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers\\DriverData", "CONDA_PREFIX=C:\\Users\\user\\.julia\\conda\\3", "FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING=Default", "SYSTEMDRIVE=C:", "FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING=Internet Explorer", "PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64", "OPENBLAS_MAIN_FREE=1"]), ProcessExited(1)) [1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scipy.optimize` is a part of `scipy` so this is all what you need:

```
julia> using Conda

julia> Conda.add("scipy");

julia> using PyCall

julia> so = pyimport("scipy.optimize")
PyObject <module 'scipy.optimize' from 'c:\\JuliaPkg\\Julia1.5.1\\conda\\3\\lib\\site-packages\\scipy\\optimize\\__init__.py'>
```